# Python Selenium Fixture test setup failed (fixture 'init_driver' not found)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-fixtures

While i'm trying to run my test to test whether the fixture work or not, I'm getting the following error

```
test setup failed
file C:\Users\user\Desktop\ssqatest\ssqatest\tests\test_dummy.py, line 6
      def test_dummy(self):
E       fixture 'web_driver' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

## **Code in conftest.py(Fixture)**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
import os


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    global driver
    supported_browsers = ['chrome', 'ch', 'headlesschrome', 'firefox', 'ff']
    browser = os.environ.get('Browser', None)
    if not browser:
        raise Exception("The environment variable 'Browser' must be set")

    browser = browser.lower()
    if browser not in supported_browsers:
        raise Exception(f"Provided browser '{browser}' is not one of the supported."
                        f"Supported are: {supported_browsers}")

    if browser in ('chrome', 'ch'):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser in ('firefox', 'ff'):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

## **Code in my test file i.e.. test_dummy.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("web_driver")
class TestDummy():

    def test_dummy(self):
        print("I'm a dummy test line 1")
        self.driver.get("https://youtube.com")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

I hope I'll get a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fixture name is `init_driver`, not `web_driver`.